# Show for $x,y \in \mathbb{X} : |d_A (x) - d_A (y)| \leq d(x,y)$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

For $A \subset \mathbb{X}$ non empty and $x \in \mathbb{X}$ define the distance of $x$ to $A$ by $$d_A (x) =  \inf \limits _{a \in A} d(x,a)$$

I am trying to show for $$x,y \in \mathbb{X} : |d_A (x) - d_A (y)| \leq d(x,y)$$
This is the proof I have.

I start with the triangle inequality: $$d(x,a) \leq d(x,y) + d(y,a)$$
I note $$d_A (x) = \inf \limits _{a \in A} d(x,a)$$ and $$d_A (y) = \inf \limits _{a \in A} d(y,a)$$

So the triangle inequality becomes $$d_A (x) \leq d(x,y) + d_A (y)$$

At this point it is obvious you rearrange to get the desired solution but that was marked as wrong and instead you change the role of $x$ and $y$.

Why is rearranging wrong?

And why do you have to change the roles of $x$ and $y$?

Comment: How exactly do you get $d_A (x) \leq d(x,y) + d_A (y)$ from what precedes this inequality? **Edit:** Don't you mean $\mathbb R$ instead of $\mathbb X$?

Comment: I think you meant $$d(x,a) \leq d(x,y) + d(y,a)$$
.

Comment: Also, you have only shown $$ d_A (x) - d_A (y) \leq d(x,y)$$
, which is not the same as what you are trying to show, even though $d_A$ is non negative.

Comment: @gitgud it is just $\mathbb{X}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding the modulus, what you want to show is equivalent to $-d(x,y) \le d_A (x) - d_A (y) \le d(x,y)$. By rearranging, you only get $d_A (x) - d_A (y) \le d(x,y)$, which is only half of what you want, and this explains why rearranging alone is not enough. Exchanging $x$ and $y$, though, will give you $d_A (y) - d_A (x) \le d(y,x)$ or, equivalently, $d_A (x) - d_A (y) \ge -d(y,x)$ which is easily seen to be the other half, and these two together are what you want to get.

Comment: out of interest, how do we know to also show that $-d(x,y) \leq d_A(x) - d_A (y)$?

Comment: @Aljabra: Take a look at my last inequality (that is obtained from the interchange) and remember that $d(x,y) = d(y,x)$ by the definition of the concept of "distance".

Comment: oh yes I remember that property, thank you

Answer (score 1):

In order to prove that $$\vert d_A (x) - d_A (y) \vert \leq d(x,y),$$ you have to prove the following two inequalities:
$$\begin{cases}
-d(x,y) \le d_A (x) - d_A (y) \\
d_A (x) - d_A (y) \le d(x,y)
\end{cases}.$$ In the question of your post, you proved the second one.

Rearranging only won't be enough to obtain the first one. However, as $x,y$ play symmetric roles, you can permute them to get the first inequality.